# Getting a 500 error with a flask post request

Tags: python, post, flask

```
from flask import render_template
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/graph', methods=['POST'])
def graph():
    fchoice = request.form['user']
    schoice = request.form['password']
    return choice + " " + choice
```

and here's the html in `index.html`:

```
<form action="/graph" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="first choice" name="user" disabled id="chose">
    <input type="text" placeholder="second choice" name="password" disabled id="chose1">

    <input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

Comment: Just pasting some code is unlikely to get you a good answer here. Could you be a bit more specific about what your actual question is?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to concatenate undefined variables.

```
return choice + " " + choice
```

You have no `choice`. You have `fchoice` and `schoice`.

```
@app.route('/graph', methods=['POST'])
def graph():
    fchoice = request.form['user']
    schoice = request.form['password']
    return fchoice + " " + schoice
```